# Black reflection on glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render a glassy flac. The problem is, taht it makes black reflections on sides or corners. I don't know where these reflections come from, almost white world and in the example the flac is in white cube and still there is black left side.

What can I do to get rid of these black spots?

[image: example]

Comment: I think this is not reflections, but due to refraction! What value did you set for the "IOR" value of the glass shader? I suggest you to try with a value closer 1.0.

Comment: I used 1.51714 as suggested here [link](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Properties/Transparency#IOR_values_for_Common_Materials). When I get to 1.2 it's almost gone, but also some of desired details disappear.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: These are probably shadows from the light.  The only way I've found to get rid of this is to disable them.

Comment: Looks to me like a combination of [total internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Internal_Reflection) and not enough transmission bounces. Note that this is in someways correct, as if light bounces around inside a piece of glass far enough, it will be absorbed pretty much completely. See e.g. [these images](https://www.google.com/search?q=glass&client=firefox-a&hs=fPE&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=8EwkVJOtCoKXoQTTgoDYCg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&q=glass)

Comment: there is an article about rendering fluid in glass I will advice you to read: http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/

Answer (score 4):

In the render properties for cycle find the **Light Paths** and increase the **Transmission** value till the dark spots go away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found it was due to my glass being shaded smooth. I added an Edge Split modifier and the black areas of refraction went away.

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent instead of glossy when the glossy ray depth is grater than the value of max glossy bounces.[image: nodes]