# Remove intersecting geometry from wire

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry

I try to render an image of a model made of optical fibre. I create it by extruding a cirle along a path. When I apply a glass material I get a very dark render image. I think this is caused by intersecting geometry.

After converting the curve object to a mesh object, I have tried to apply a boolean modifier (Operation: Intersect, Solver: Carve) with a cube. Unfortunately this operation results in an error message ("Cannot execute boolean operation").

[image: optical fibre object]

Comment: Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16157/black-reflection-on-glass or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41594/glass-shader-appears-black-when-touching-another-object

Comment: Increase transparency bounces see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects adn https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes

Comment: Increasing the values for transparency, bounces  and transmission does not solve the problem. Caustics is enabled.