# Eye model in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was following a tutorial on modeling and coloring an eye mesh at website called Blender Basics.

I want the render to look like the image on the left:[image]

Here's the download if anyone would like to see what is going wrong. [image]

Comment: it doesn't look like you have any light source in your scene

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Grace.G!  We could use a few more details in order to better understand your situation.  What does your mesh look like?  What do your material nodes look like?  What do you want the render to look like?  You could even [upload your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (or a simplified version of it) and post the link in your question.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: I did look at that related link, but my render still looks like a tadpole egg rather than an eye ball like in the image i posted above.

Comment: So i mostly solved the problem by following this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38568/can-a-glass-object-be-made-to-act-completely-transparent-to-only-the-object-cont

After creating a new file the render, for the most part, came out fine but the objects are still dark.

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1607" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1607/)