# Why is there no light passing through the window?

Tags: materials, light

I have attached a screen shot of no light passing through the window. The light strength is high, and the glass material I think is good. Why is there not a pinch of light passing or traveling inside the room. In the image the window glass is all black. What is missing in my nodes, so that light can travel inside the room? 
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The glass shader has to be modified to let light through. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: @cegaton u mean the addon archimesh im using material is of no use. I have to change the glass material

Comment: yes, change the glass material. You need to mix a glass shader and a transparent shader controlled by light paths  http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47875/1853

Comment: i have applied the material still not get the result http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71654/why-no-lights-enter-the-room

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a bit to the glass shader to make light pass through it, like it would through a window.
Try using this node setup, works really well for architectural glass: 
[image: png]

Comment: Thanks for the reply in the node where the Add came im mean which shader

Comment: sorry to disturb you in the add as you said mixRGB in image it show value and im getting color

Comment: Oh my bad, it's actually the math node you're supposed to use, just connect the light paths in the value inputs.

Comment: i have applied the material still not get the result http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71654/why-no-lights-enter-the-room