# Why no lights enter the room

Tags: light

I have apply glass material and sun is in the position everything looks good but no lights enter the room. I have added hdr file and a lamp. Whats the reason what im missing to get light enter the room. All black inside the room and just the hdr image is seen from the window. In the red mark there is no light. And in green mark where the edge is coming from as there is no wall. And from the window the background look so artificial.[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71570/why-is-there-no-light-passing-through-the-window

Comment: @PaulGonet thats my question in that and i did not get the answer i need why there is no light passing the room i have the glass material perfect still no light enter. plz download the file and go through and tell me where im going wrong thanks

Comment: If you need to add more information to a question, clarify that the provided answers do not work or that your question isn't a duplicate you should use the 'edit' button below your question to update it instead of asking the same question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is indeed a duplicate.

What you need to to do is change the glass material:

[image]

[image]

As suggested before: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

[image]

Comment: may i know from where the maximum came

Comment: Add>Converter>Math and set the operaton to maximum

Comment: sorry im back i have attach my images im not getting the result you showed. I have applied the material and the spot light strength 100 with the suggestion given. still no lights What else missing plz

Comment: See edited answer for the blend file.

Comment: i did not get what you mean