# Reflective and transparent material on poster

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I'm doing an interior scene and on one of the walls, I have a poster with a thin fram around it. To make it a little bit more realistic, I want to create a material just like a thin and transparent plastic board above the poster with reflections.

I made a separate object close to the poster, but I guess I could also apply this effect on the image texture?

But anyway, I tested to use window glass materials like this, but it is perhaps too much reflections:

[How can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader)

Any suggestions of node combinations to create a transparent and reflective plastic material or reflections on image texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not need anything like refractions, I don't think you need to consider the Glass shader.

In this situation, I would personally create a simple mix of Transparent and Glossy shader, and adjust the mix until you got the look that you wanted. Obviously it will be a mix of high transparency, and just a little glossy.

To get a physically accurate result, you could use the Fresnel or Layer Weight nodes to control the mix (so you get more Glossy on the glancing angle, and less Glossy when viewed straight on). Add a Math node to multiply the Fresnel and you can play around until you get the result you want.