# lighting problems, sun isn't working on render

Tags: light, lighting

I am trying to create an indoor enviroment. I made two windows, added a sun and rotated it so that it could go throug the window and lighten the sofa and part of the wall.
But I don't see the sun light anywhere.

I checked on settings and is not invisible to the render but it just not reflecting any light. The only light I get is from the image background.

This is the picture with sun 
[image]

and this is when I delete the sun
[image]

Can anybody tell me please why is this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add more information. Do the windows have a glass shader? If so, you need to modify it. Please read these links:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Hello cegaton. I did that but as I didn't see any results I just deleted the window and it didn't work either.

Comment: Please read the links again, the shader you show is not the way to let light through the glass shader. To help you better consider uploading your file

Comment: Here is the file. I had to delete some objects because it was too big. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3558" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3558/)

Comment: If you want to use a glass shader use this setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvM59.jpg here's the blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3559/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sun is working fine but the size is huge, it is making shadows very soft and blurry.

Reduce the *Size* parameter to something below 0.1 units if you want hard shadows.
[image]

Comment: I had it on 0.1 as preset but then I tried to follow a tutorial but it didn't work for me. I will try this again anyways. Thank you very much

Comment: @NATURUNATURYU If the answer solves your problem consider marking it as accepted