# Why no light travelling inside the window

Tags: light, glass

I have made a simple model with the window with archimesh addon. With the window material i have set to travel the light inside.

[image]

But no light travel inside through the window

[image]

What is missing the blend file attach below

[image]

Comment: Direct light will not go through the standard glass shader. Read: [how can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader?r=SearchResults)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using glossy shader instead of glass?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your material is the issue, when the light outside the window was changed to these settings:

[image]

This was the result:

[image]

So I would suggest taking another look at the scene in general because the window material is obviously working properly as it is both translucent and letting light pass through, hope that helps :)