# sun lamp is turning window white for some reason

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, lighting

[image]

I have an hdri and a sun lamp. I am not sure why the window is turning white? I have attatched a picture of the node set up of the window material.  [image]

Comment: Whether or not it's related, I'm not sure (haven't been able to test) but that second Mix node with an unconnected input socket doesn't look right - it will be mixing between your glass/transparent and *nothing* (which will be interpreted as a pure black shader under Cycles). If you really do want it to be a 'black' shader under that circumstance then best to connect one explicitly. Otherwise, connect a suitable shader (100% transparent, perhaps).

Comment: I have no idea of what you are trying to accomplish with such node tree. To have direct light go through glass try this: [How can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader)

Comment: I’ve tried to replicate this and the only reason I can see for that second Mix Shader node with an unconnected socket is to disable the refractive caustics from the glass onto any diffuse surfaces - and for that it does work - but that isn’t the cause of your problem. Is there another mesh in the window behind the glass? Perhaps with a Translucent shader or maybe Glass with a high roughness?