# How To Render Glass Materials in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

First: After modeling, I render the **Object in Blender**, it was fine to me or in my eyes. See the Image.

[image]

Second: I tried to render the **Object in Cycles** since the **Glass Material** which I downloaded from the internet was made for Cycles. It's not fine to me or to anyone at all. There is no light, and the worst is the **Glass Material didn't apply to the Object**. See the image below.

[image]

Finally: The image below is the **Settings in the Material Box**. So, how to make it to be like the first image (that is the glass material) rendered in Blender, to be able to work in Cycles?

[image]

Comment: In the bottom image you posted, there's a box that says "Viewport Alpha" which is set to _Opaque_. What happens if you change it from opaque to something else?

Comment: I have tried all such as, **Alpha Anti-Aliasing, Alpha Sort, Alpha Blend, Alpha Clip, Add, then Opaque** ; they are with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure about the downloaded pack you are using, but blender has a built-in Glass BSDF shader that is meant for cycles (I'm assuming you're using 2.79 - I think it should be there). Just click the "use nodes" button, split your view so you can make one window a shader graph, add a Glass shader Node, and connect it to the material output.

Comment: Related Q's about glass... [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles) and  [How can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader)

Comment: Alright, @ Christopher Bennett; I have done that, but the glass material is darker also looks too tick, rather than light as it in the Blender Render. I will try to work on it, then if unsuccessful, I will post my difficulty again. Here I downloaded the Glass Material [link] http://blendermada.com/materials/detail/79-clear-glass-material/

Comment: Oh, @ChristopherBennett just now I viewed properly at the link I sent you where I downloaded the **Glass Material** to find out that it was truly meant for **Blender Internal** but others were for **Cycles Render**. Could it be the reason why it rendered aptly in Blender and giving me headache in Cycles? I hope I'm not mistaken or complicating both?

Comment: @Timaroberts, I have bookmarked the link you sent me, I will make time to study it, but using already made seemed to be saving time, which was my reason to grab those materials from the net.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not familiar at all with the material pack you have, and it's been quite some time since I used blender internal. I'm not sure how else to really help. Maybe try mixing a Transparent or Translucent shader with a Glossy and then adjusting the roughness to get that "plastic" look That's all I can really think of at the moment.

Comment: @FrankfortStainlesscoin   [this Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal) might be useful to have a look at to understand some of the differences between the two engines, materials are fundamentally different. Now that internal has been removed, you will be better to learn cycles.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, yeah I will try to play around with your last suggestions. Then I will post the final result whenever I finish the modeling, (if I will remember the promise).

Comment: @Timaroberts, The same in my hitherto assertion, 'bookmarked...'I wanted to send greetings but we weren't allowed to do so. But in everything everyone who helped another understands that while lecturing others, he is learning likewise.