# Getting hard shadows through glass material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, glass, hdri

I am attempting to emulate what's seen in the image below:

[image]

I have an indoor scene that's fully surrounded by walls. The only way in for light is the glass skylight at the top.

[image]

When I render the image with an HDRI and without the object representing the top glass, I get very hard shadows correctly aligned to match the concept art.

[image]

I'd like to keep the shadows while introducing the glass material, but as soon as I add the glass, the light gets foggy and dark.

[image]

These are the settings for the glass material. I've played with the settings but nothing seems to help.

[image]

How can I have an object with a material representing the glass while achieving full light transmission and hard shadows?

Comment: Without further instruction the principled bsdf will still cast a shadow.  Related post here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213181/is-glass-in-cycles-just-broken-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/213186#213186

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.5726

Comment: I'd suggest that you simply avoid using the glass altogether since Cycles struggles with transmission of refracted light. Also, reflections on the glass usually aren't visible from the inside of a building.

Comment: The top two comments seem to work. @HISEROD what would you suggest using instead of the glass shader?

Comment: I would either leave the window frames completely empty or use a shader that transmits light using just the Transparent BSDF like in the first linked answer.

Comment: I recommend using the Glass shader node instead so as to avoid questionable Principled settings, but aside from that, you may be able to use the Ray information node to have only direct rays from the glass be refracted.