# Make glass lightbulb material work?

Tags: materials, light

I am making an old fashioned incandescent light bulb in cycles, with the coil inside having an emissive material. However, I am trying to find a good way to make the glass material. If I use an actual glass material with low roughness, it is too dim. If I use a glass material with high roughness, I can't see the filament, which I want to see. The best way to pass the light through that I found was a completely transparent material, but then you obviously cant see the glass. Is there any way to make a material that passes light through like a transparent bsdf but still shows up?[image]

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/204810/110840

Comment: @AllenSimpson Tried that, didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I would think you could use a principled shader with the transmission level set to 1.  Here's a demo scene:

[image: demo scene with two spheres on a plane]

There's a cylinder inside the first sphere and it acts as the filament:

[image: wireframe showing filament inside sphere]

The plane and the back sphere have simple principled shaders.  The only changed setting on either is the color.

The front sphere has a principled shader with roughness well down and transmission set to 1:

[image: fake glass principled shader settings]

[image: simple fake glass shader node group]

Note: if you look at this scene in Lookdev/Viewport shading you won't see the filament because EEVEE is used in lookdev:

[image: no filament in lookdev mode]

My world emits no light and there are no other lights in the scene but the filament:

[image: dark world]

and the filament is just an emitter:

[image: filament shader node group]

The blackbody simply sets the color to daylight.

Here's the render view with that setup:

[image: render view]

or you can set the color to reddish by changing the temperature to 1500:

[image: reddish light]

or lower the intensity of the bulb:

[image: low intensity light]

note that the yellow outline of the cylinder is because it's selected.  Here's an actual render:

[image: actual render]

Comment: Using that with a slightly higher roughness works, but now I have weird square artifacts in my render. I'm adding a picture to the original post. Any ideas? I am running at 128 samples and double light bounces.