# Removing black-ish tint in beveled area of clear glass

Tags: modeling, node-editor, shaders

I can not seem to gt rid of the really annoying BLACK that always seems to show up in Blender Cycles when rendering glass. I've even used a transparent shader to NO avail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if it helps - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles. It could be not enough transparent bounces or not proper rendering of caustics

Comment: Thanks. I increased the transparency from 8 to 20 (both Min / Max) I increased bounces to 12 (both Min / Max) --absolutely no change. I inceased the IQR from 1.4 to to 2.0 nano change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a material fix that I applied that seemed to head toward what you were wanting. Same basic components, just re-arranged a little.

[image]

I think you can get your reflections back using a method something like this afterward:

[image]

If you want to get even more of the reflection back you can just keep the progression of your mix nodes, something like this:

[image]

Comment: My glass disappeas with those same settings...

Comment: Plus with your screen capture it seems to lose the reflection of the actual light source showing on the glass.

Comment: @Marc - I've just appended my answer to hopefully help you on this. It's going to be subjective, so play with the values until you are satisfied.

Comment: --Complex! But you nailed it. Now I have to try and understand it. I can't thank you enough. Someone should write a book just on nodes.