# How can I accomplish the Iron Man in helmet effect around the head with out a black or green screen?

Tags: masking, effects

I've been looking in to making an Iron Man inspired HUD Anim, but I cant figure out a way to get the fading around the head so that it gets darker, and I'm not sure how to use a mask to do this, and even if I use a feather or edge blur, I'm not getting the result I'm looking for. So, how would i go about accomplishing this (hopefully w/out sitting for hours doing rotoscoping)?
What I've got (if I add feather, I get a bg that has lots of different colors, etc.):  [image: pic]

Comment: Could you please provide some pictures/examples of what you currently obtain compared to what you want to obtain ? Are you using Blender Internal rendering or Cycles ?

Comment: blender internal, pics coming right up.

Comment: Are you talking about some of the FX found [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIaeABAkXpc)? Specifically the 33 sec. Mark?

Comment: yes, specifically the fading around the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this and see if it gets you close to where you want to be:

It's going to be subjective, so play with the Mix Fac to see if that does the trick for you.

[image]

[image]

ALTERNATIVELY You could start doing something like this as well.
For the right transition, you may have to layer a few more iterations of things before you nail it ( Somthing Like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50871/removing-black-ish-tint-in-beveled-area-of-clear-glass/50884#50884) ).

[image]

!!Appended Since Comments Below!!

Here's an example of layering some of these effects (It May be a poor one, but it should give you a little more perspective). Also I've attached the blend so you can look at the setup a little closer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention one thing. On the second mask with the size option set to fixed, My Scene res was set to 50% of 1920 x 1080. So to get the numbers correct I scaled the mask up by a factor of 1.1 on each axis. ((1920*0.5)*1.1) x ((1080*0.5)*1.1).

Comment: but how do i get the area around the head to be black, what you sowed so far is what i managed to do as well, but I didn't put that in the pic, what I manly what to know is how to get every thing but my body to become black.

Comment: You might have to get creative with contrast. This is always a major struggle. you either get a good matte/keying background/good lighting/low shadows, OR you spend a lot of time rotoscoping, OR you live with what you can get with node type creativity such as in this post. Again I would try layering some of this to get a better result, I'll see if I can spend some time editing my answer to show you more specifically what I mean by layering.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/COt3kTDhi10 this vid might help. I'd def start with a better lit face though. Starting with that dark image, you are making more work for yourself on the backend. Is start with a well lit face, which gives you more room to darken the edges around the face later. Maybe a mask, darkened and feathered on the inside to give a sort of vignette effect, then tint the face a little to stimulate the elements in the HUD reflecting off the face.

Comment: Links can go down. If you add some details, your answer instantly improves.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nodes grouped under the *matte* menu  that can be used to unspill those colors at the edges.

I also recommend the dilate/erode filter on your feathered mask to fine tune it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: my main issue with you solution is that I don't have a solid or semi solid color to work with, so that doesn't help much.