# glass in outer eye blurry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I tried to make the outer eye has a transparent effect / reflection so I add the glass material but the effect still has some blurry on it, how can I make the outer eye have a transparent and clear reflection (not blurry)? I've tried to add lighting, making the new object but it does not work [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not blur, this is noise, due to insufficient amount of ray bounces, if you take a look at the reflection, it's not blurred, the white and black pixels making the noise are because of the rays are not able to collect enough data because they are set to low bounce values.
Try one of two things:
**First:** instead of using Glass Shader, use an Add Shader to connect a Glossy Shader and a Transparent Shader, you might need to tweak the parameters of both shaders to meet your requirements, keep in mind this will not give you any refraction, but it should eliminate the noise and keep the glossy reflection. If you don't like what you get with an Add Shader, you can use a Mix Shader instead, and add an Input Node called "Layer Weight", use Fresnel as a Factor, then you can tweak the Blend in Layer Weight Node in order to get the effect you want.

**Second:** Go to Render Panel, under Light Paths menu, change the Integrator Presets into Full Global Illumination.
Aside from that, if you are planning not to use any kind of roughness in the Glossy Shader, put it to "Sharp" instead of "GGX" or "Beckman" this will tell Cycles not to calculate roughness, so changing roughness values will not do a thing, also if you still need some roughness, my advise is to use Ashikhmin-Shirley method instead of "GGX" or "Beckman", it gives better results, specially when the roughness is less than 0.7.
Hope this helps, Happy Blending!

Comment: instead of the Add shader for glass try this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BseqZ.png you can then keep the refraction. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Wow, I'll try that, I had the same problem few days ago as fahri chaerul, and I solved it as I'm mentioning in my answer, but this... looks just awesome!

Comment: I just tried it and it's supper awesome, it's noise free even in viewport render! @fahrichaerul I believe you should go with this solution.

Comment: thanks you very much georges, cegaton for the reply, i'll try it right away :)

happy blending too!