# Creating realistic glass material with control over transparency

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, shaders

I`m trying to create a glass box with objects inside, basically a display case.
On another thread here I found the setup for a realistic glass material, however the result seems very dark.[image]
The relation between reflections and the objects showing through seems ok, but the wall behind is completely white and the glass seems quite grey. Imagining a glass box in real life it seems to me it should be almost transparent.
I used a simple cube and added the glass material to it. Is the cube rendered as a solid glass body or are only the planes making up the surface rendered as glass. And how would my setup have to look like for either situation (1) solid (2) glass walls.
If this dark grey glass is not due to some mistake I made in the setup, is there a way to make it ligher or more transparent in any way?

UPDATE: I found out that I have to use the solidify modifier to have walls instead of a solid chunk of glass. I now have 2mm thick walls, however the glass still seeems grey. the main change seems to be the reflection which has gotten stronger.
[image]

Comment: Please read this related (possible duplicate) post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles. The node setup could be something [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EG73x.jpg)

Comment: You glass box looks like a solid block which wont yield a physically correct solution. Mix a *Transparent* shader into your glass shader to reduce the darkening

Comment: Try turning the IOR down to 1.000 to rule out refraction effects - and make sure that the Colour of the Glass and Transparent shaders are both pure white rather than grey.

Comment: This could be the old "glass with infinite thickness" problem. Your glass is only a plane, isn't it? Give the glass some thickness to end the glass.

Comment: Also... that's not a realistic glass shader. I have no idea why it's adding those two values, except maybe to make it faster. That shader is almost *exactly* the same as just using a plain glass shader (which isn't necessarily a bad idea).

Comment: ...also reset your Light Path Integrator to the "Full Global-Illumination" preset. Your current settings might be causing the problem because you don't have enough bounces. Always optimize AFTER it works/looks correct... and even then, only if speed is actually a problem. A better speed improvement would be to change "Dynamic BVH" to "Static BVH." Dynamic is good for scenes with moving stuff in them. Static is faster for scenes that are mostly... static.