# Why are my Reflections colored?

Tags: rendering, materials, glass

I've been working on a ruby material and I think is pretty good so far but it has a major error that I don't know how to fix. Every reflection on the faces of the ruby are colored and this is unrealistic as the reflections should be white.

[image: render result with colored reflections]

Any help to fix this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: To help you, more information is needed. Please add an image of the nodes you are using for the materials. if you are using any glossy nodes they should have no color. Same with glass node. Color should come from volume absorption.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76262/1853

Answer (score 2):

Glass should have no color.

If you give a glass shader a color,  you will get, as you pointed out in the question, "unrealistic" relfections. The reflections should indeed be untinted.

Here's an example:

[image]

What gives glass color mainly is the light that is absorbed as it goes through the surface.

A volume absorption node will give you a more realistic result, with "white reflections".

To understand when you should have colored highlights you can watch 
 Andrew Price's video on the principled shader (https://youtu.be/4H5W6C_Mbck?t=646). The important concept is that dielectric Materials (including glass) will not have colored highlights. Reflections on metallic materials will be tinted with the color of the material.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213478/why-dont-dielectric-materials-have-coloured-reflections-like-conductors

[image]