# Change emission without affecting material color though glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, light

I know that I can change the emission value of a material without increase the brightness of the object using *"Is Camera Ray"* socket of *Light Path* node, but how do I change it when the light is coming to camera through a glass?
[image]

This above is the result I get when both emission values are the same.

But then, when I increase the emission to 100, the area where there's no glass it's fine, but through glass the *Light Path* node doesn't work.

How can I make the glass doesn't interfere on the brightness of the material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a math node to add **Is Camera Ray** to **Is Transmission Ray**.

In this example the cube emits red rays for the camera and trough transparent materials, but emits green for all other rays.

[image]

Note also that for the light to go through the glass shader you might need the following node setup:

[image]
as described in this link:[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Comment: Got it! It worked perfectly, thank you so much