# light path glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

i have add a transparent image as plane behind the glass curve.
But, as you can see in the screenshot, behind the curved glass i see dark part of the plane (1) and not the clean plant (2).
How fix it?
Regards
Carmelo

[image: render preview]
[image: glass material]

[image: position of image as plane]

Comment: try turning up the transmission light bounces.

Comment: Instead of adding a  new emitter change the glass shader to let light trough: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles