# Glass material not rendering as expected in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency, glass

The glass material in one of my scenes is not rendering as expected. It is a simple shadowless glass material I have used countless times. In an attempt to track down the reason, I created a duplicate of an existing scene (GlassCorrect.blend) in which the shader is working and deleted every object except for an eyeball with a glass shell, lights and a camera. Then I created a duplicate of my problem scene (GlassIncorrect.blend), deleted all objects and the world, and appended the objects and world from the first scene. The glass is rendering without any transparency, just reflecting the world around it. Please help me figure out what is going wrong.

Thank you.

[image: GlassCorrect]
[image: GlassIncorrect]
[GlassCorrect.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48500)
[GlassIncorrect.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48501)

Comment: Please don't use pasteall to share your files. Links on that site expire after some time and users who might want to learn from your files will not have access to them once the link is gone. Consider using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ instead.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you will need to check **Shadows** under **Light Pass** tab.

[image: 1]

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Not sure how it got unchecked. Thank you!