# Lighting a room with true to life lamps

Tags: lighting

Ok, I know that this question must have been asked before, but I am having a hard time finding the right posts or finding an online tutorial which will help me get past this.  Here goes:

I am trying to replicate my basement right now and I am struggling to get the two lights which I have in the basement to correctly light the room.  It seems as though the picture is very grainy and does not get a lot of light although I have the lamp power turned way up.  I have downloaded a simple light fixture from online and then placed a lamp inside of it.  I have tried to use area and point lights with no real success.  I have edited the "glass" material to be a mix between the glass and the transparent shaders.

I am really at my wits end as this is simply not working as my gut would tell me.  Also, there seems to be a large difference between when I render the scene and when I just change the viewport mode to show rendered.  I would be grateful for any help on this.  Any other advice is also welcome.  I am not a blender regular and just starting to get my hands dirty here.

## Configuration

Setup is OSX 10.13.1.  CPU rendering on Blender 2.79.  Using Cycles

## Blend file

[image]

## Example Images

### Render

[image]

### Viewport Render

*Note: This image was scaled to meet the max file upload requirements of 2MB*

[image]

Comment: [This tutorial is probably the best ever for realistic lighting.](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/realistic-lighting-in-blender.html) (Does cost money)

Comment: The default glass material in cycles will not let direct light go through. Use the tricky glass node setup described in this link: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles). Also Hemi lights do not work on cycles.