# Why i cant see the poster through transparent material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, glass

I have 2 transparent sheet top and bottom and between both there is a poster (image) and emission from bottom. Why i cant see the poster through the transparent sheet and also the emission i have given is white color but its showing red color. May i know why the poster is not display and the emission is red.

[image]

[image]

Transparent Material
[image]

**Looking for this type of effect**

[image]

Comment: @cegaton plz im attaching the file due to low internet file is enable sorry for it

Comment: @cegaton now the file attach.

Comment: please make an effort to describe your scene, materials, etc. Don't make questions that rely on others downloading the file only.

Comment: @cegaton i have edited the question and reference image what effect im looking for

Comment: On the second mix shader you don't have an input. That will make it black.

Comment: See: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: @cegaton why emission light change its white but showing red

Comment: All you need is a light to show the poster, right? I don't understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the poster&LED plane between the two light emission planes.

As in the file you posted:
[image: Before]

After moving the poster&LED plane into the middle
[image]

After moving the poster&LED plane down the image starts to appear
[image]

Comment: But in real life the poster is in middle and the led is at the back end so its not the answer i think so

Comment: @atek if you want light to go through the image you will need to make it slightly transparent. The problem at the moment is the image sheet is fully blocking out the light from the backlight