# Rendering Glass (layers) resulting in strange dark patches (in Final but not Preview)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, glass

I am working on a school research project and hence I cannot share the blender file (confidentiality BS). I am getting strange lines in the render where there are stacked "glass" tiles. This occurs only in the final render and not in the preview render. I have tried the following but to no avail:

1. Increasing spacing in between (the tiles are not touching each other)
2. Increase light rays
3. Smooth Shade Toggle and Edge Split Toggle
4. Toggling Caustics
5. Changed Material from Glass to Principled shader

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OERauRJs8S7BAYAZq7S64UlmmxdvrcSL

[image]

Final Render (500 samples)

[image: Preview Render]

Preview Render (32 samples)

[image]

Final Render (1000 Samples)

[image]

Preview Render (1000 samples)

[image: Edge Split Modifier]

[image: Render Settings]

Comment: Check your scene objects if some have rendering flag disabled. Check your modifiers if you have different values in Render / Preview. Does it render the same way if you use 32 samples in Render as you do in preview?

Comment: I don't have an idea which lines do you mean and where to search for them. Either mark them on the images or crop images to adjacent area. Generally if there are black lines in the render of glass with multiple layers then Transparency bounces should be increased in Render tab > Light Paths panel

Comment: Furthermore, I can't seem to see the difference between the first two images on first sight. Please add more information to make that clear.

Comment: @MrZak I increased it to 500. There was no change

Comment: @Leander  I have marked the stuff that I am talking about

Comment: @kheetor Checked everything you mentioned. And final render at 32 samples still gives those artefacts

Comment: Have attached the blender file. Please have look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an object hidden in the viewport that is showing up in the render.

Look for a setting in the outliner similar to this and either hide that object in the render or delete it:

[image]

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and you should see all hidden objects in the viewport. Then you can select and delete/disable anything you need to.

This script will automatically hide all objects in the render that are hidden in the viewport:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.hide and not obj.hide_render:
        obj.hide_render = True
```

---

Putting this here for reference...

[Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67490/28015)

Comment: Why do you think that is the cause? I checked the entire object list. Everything is visible.

Comment: @PrasannaRN Perhaps you are not viewing the correct scene in the outliner? It certainly looks like artifacts caused by overlapping geometry on the floor and maybe some black object at the top.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. I have attached the blender file with just the floor tiles. Please have a look. It now looks likes those artefacts also appear in the preview render. Can they be the surface patches themselves? The tiles were made in Solidworks

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that even though you are using a principled BSDF shader, and not the regular glass shader,
[image]

you might be facing the same issue as described here: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles),  where cycles is not rendering caustics correctly.

Adding a light path node to control the mix with a transparent shader will allow for direct light to illuminate through the glass.

[image]

[image]

On top of that you might have other issues related to the clipping distance range for the camera being too large, which might reduce precision causing z fighting on surfaces that are close together... and then the topology of the objects might be adding other issues. I don't know. Maybe someone with more patience can address those in a different question.