# Noisy Animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction, denoise

[image]
I'm new to Blender. I just animated a waterwheel but the water seems very noisy and grainy. Can anyone help me to sort this out ?

I rendered this with Cycle's rendering engine.
I don't have a GPU in my PC

Comment: please upload your .blend file and tell us what you already tried to fix it, as their is a ton of information out there to reduce noise.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2558/599