# Why do my lights appear like this (opaque) behind the glass shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, artifacts

I'm currently working on an animation where the camera starts filming infront of a fireplace and then slowly goes back and then flys through the window. There the problem appears. As soon as I render the scene from behind the glass my lights look like this. I assume this is some basic and easy to solve issue but I couldn't figure out what it is. Can anyone help me out?

[image: infront of glass - everthing is fine]

[image: behind the glass - everything is weird]

[image: My settings for fast renders. I tried higher values but nothing changed]

[image: This is the Glass shader thats probably causing the issue]

Comment: Looking at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117633/no-light-or-transparency-through-glass-and-water-objects-using-various-transpare?rq=1), do you have _Properties > Scene > Simplify_ unchecked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)