# Eye gone dark with light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, compositing-nodes, glass

I'm having trouble with the eye, I been follow tutorial of making an eye then it skip the set of light and my eye came up with very dark glass.

I've been researchin for a long time but nothing helps.
[image]

To left eye is outer eye in glass and inner eye texture
To right eye is just outer eye.
Both are very dark with or without lighting

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Are your lights bright enough? If you add a cube and it is also dark, then just increase the brightness of the lights.

Comment: Yes, I have a character model and the light it bright and working but as I try to shiny to eye, it didn’t bright it