# My glass has a smudge

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, glass, artifacts, denoise

[image]
I made a cup with a glass by setting transmission to 1 and roughness to 0. So I somewhat made it like above. However, As you can see if you zoom in it. there are several points to improve such as smudges on the glass or some artifact border along the side of the cup.

I'm using blender 2.80.75 and Cycles with GPU computed device and in the view layer, I'm using also Denoising Data feature with the default setting.

How can I fix this? I also have googled this, but couldn't find what I want that remove artifacts and smudges.

[image]

Comment: Looks like artefacts produced by the denoiser that smudge the reflection.

Comment: @rjg but without the denoiser, there are a lot of black noises even with 512 samplings

Comment: You may have to increase the max bounces for the transmission. Can you upload your file so we can take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: I have uploaded it, and I cranked sampling up to 512 and changed my shader from the Principled BSDF to the Glass BSDF according to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

**EDIT**: I also changed Total and Transmission to 24 in the Light Paths > Max Bounces

Comment: The version with the increased max bounces looks fine to me. If you want the denoiser to preserve more details, reduce the filter size and/or play around with the strength.

Comment: @rig Thanks for your advice, I found that I don't have basic knowledge about blender and 3D graphics, thus I gotta start from the beginning in the blender manual.